# Cassandra SSTableLoader : failed to list files in <directory_path>

Tags: java, cassandra

I am following the Cassandra Bulk Loader example for Cassandra 3.4.0 from here https://github.com/yukim/cassandra-bulkload-example . The data files are generated under data folder. These are as follows :

```
quote-historical_prices-ka-1-CompressionInfo.db  quote-historical_prices-ka-1-Index.db
quote-historical_prices-ka-1-Data.db             quote-historical_prices-ka-1-Statistics.db
quote-historical_prices-ka-1-Digest.sha1         quote-historical_prices-ka-1-TOC.txt
quote-historical_prices-ka-1-Filter.db
```

however when trying to load these using `sstableloader -d 127.0.0.1 ~/workspace/cassandra-bulkload-example/data/quote/historical_prices/` i get an error as follows :

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Failed to list files in /home/srai/workspace/cassandra-bulkload-example/data/quote/historical_prices
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to list files in /home/srai/workspace/cassandra-bulkload-example/data/quote/historical_prices
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.list(LogAwareFileLister.java:53)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LifecycleTransaction.getFiles(LifecycleTransaction.java:544)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.openSSTables(SSTableLoader.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:165)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.openForBatch(SSTableReader.java:431)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.lambda$openSSTables$220(SSTableLoader.java:121)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.lambda$innerList$208(LogAwareFileLister.java:75)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
        at java.util.TreeMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2965)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.innerList(LogAwareFileLister.java:77)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.list(LogAwareFileLister.java:49)
        ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to list files in /home/srai/workspace/cassandra-bulkload-example/data/quote/historical_prices
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:93)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to list files in /home/srai/workspace/cassandra-bulkload-example/data/quote/historical_prices
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.list(LogAwareFileLister.java:53)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LifecycleTransaction.getFiles(LifecycleTransaction.java:544)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.openSSTables(SSTableLoader.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:165)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:80)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.openForBatch(SSTableReader.java:431)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.lambda$openSSTables$220(SSTableLoader.java:121)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.lambda$innerList$208(LogAwareFileLister.java:75)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
        at java.util.TreeMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2965)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.innerList(LogAwareFileLister.java:77)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.list(LogAwareFileLister.java:49)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Please mention which Java version you are using.

Comment: @Akki : I am using java version "1.8.0_77"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk loader example by default builds sstables for [2.1.12](https://github.com/yukim/cassandra-bulkload-example/blob/604f0010d961e50ab1d36d0bf0421c1a892adbdd/build.gradle#L6). Streaming < 3.0.0 tables is not supported, This was brought up for not skip or provide good error before [CASSANDRA-10940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10940).  However, in 3.5 they will start supporting it again in [CASSANDRA-10990](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10990).

So either build the sstables in the newer version or wait for 3.5.

Comment: I tried changing the cassandra_version from 2.1.12 to 3.4.0 in build.gradle. However it seems not correct as the project shows errors. I changed cassandra_version to 2.2.0 and it can also compile but same problem.  What version should i define so i can use sstableloader?

Comment: 3.4.0 doesn't exist, after 3.0 the versioning changed a little. It would just be 3.4. 3.0.4 should work too though